# nested table with different alingnment

Tags: css

I have nested table and I want **Table1** to be center align and **Table2** to be left align but it is not working for me.

Here is my code.

```
<table id="contenttable" width="600" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center !important; margin-top:0 !important; margin-right: auto !important; margin-bottom:0 !important; margin-left: auto !important; border:none; width: 100% !important; max-width:600px !important;">
<tr>
   <td width="100%">
       <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align = "center">Table1 </table>
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align = "left">Table2</table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css will display like you want.

```
#contenttable table {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 20px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

You have given 100% width to both table. Make it smaller will look like you want.

And you need to add text inside `<td>`

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1gajesf/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
<table id="contenttable" width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center !important; margin-top:0 !important; margin-right: auto !important; margin-bottom:0 !important; margin-left: auto !important; border:none; width: 100% !important; max-width:600px !important;">
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
                <td>Table1 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="text-align: left;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Table2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```